# Efficiently replacing values in each row of pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to work with a pandas data frame to get a strange yet desired output dataframe. For each row, I'd like any values of 0.0 to be replaced with an empty string (''), and all values of 1.0 to be replaced with the value of the index. Any given value on a row can only be 1.0 or 0.0.

Here's some example data:

```
# starting df
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':[1.0,0.0,0.0],'B':[1.0,1.0,0.0],'C':[0.0,1.0,1.0]})
df.index=['x','y','z']
print(df)
```

What the input df looks like:

```
     A    B    C
x  1.0  1.0  0.0
y  0.0  1.0  1.0
z  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

What I would like the output df to look like:

```
   A  B  C
x  x  x   
y     y  y
z        z
```

So far I've got this pretty inefficient but seemingly working code:

```
for idx in df.index:
    df.loc[idx] = df.loc[idx].map(str).replace('1.0',str(idx))
    df.loc[idx] = df.loc[idx].map(str).replace('0.0','')
```

Could anyone please suggest an efficient way to do this?

The real data frame I'll be working with has a shape of (4548, 2044) and the values will always be floats (1.0 or 0.0), like in the example. I'm manipulating the usher_barcodes.csv data from "raw.githubusercontent.com/andersen-lab/Freyja/main/freyja/data/…" into a format required by another pipeline, where the column headers are lineage names and the values are mutations (taken from the index). The column headers and index values will likely be different each time I need to run this code because the lineage assignments are constantly changing.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok but why? What is the wider problem you're solving? What does the 4548x2044 dataframe represent? Sales? Genetics? And are your dataframe values bools, floats or strings? Without telling us the context, it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The dataframe values will always be floats (1.0 or 0.0), like in the example. I'm manipulating the usher_barcodes.csv data from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andersen-lab/Freyja/main/freyja/data/usher_barcodes.csv" into a format required by another pipeline, where the column headers are lineage names and the values are mutations (taken from the index).

Comment: frustrated_bioinformatician: ok, please edit that context into the question. I recommend you **don't** replace the one values with the (string) index value, show us the next computation, let's figure out how to access the index values (e.g. look at [`df.to_records()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html)). Ultimately I presume it only gets used in some string-formatted output; but there are other ways to implement that, so probably better kept as ones/zeros.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. For better or worse, the pipeline takes as input a CSV file where each column contains diagnostic mutations for each lineage of interest (the column headers). By nature of this, not all columns have the same number of values, and a 1.0/0.0 format wouldn't be accepted. Here's what the test input mutation sheet looks like: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIMSBbioinfo/pigx_sars-cov-2/main/tests/sample_data/mutation_sheet_211006_covidCG_NT_location.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with broadcasting index convert to numpy array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.eq(1), 
                           df.index.to_numpy()[:, None], 
                           ''),
                   index = df.index, 
                   columns = df.columns)

print(df)
   A  B  C
x  x  x   
y     y  y
z        z
```

**Performance** with data by size `(4548,2044)`:

```
np.random.seed(2023)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0.0,1.0], size=(4548,2044))).add_prefix('c')
df.index = df.index.astype(str) + 'r'
# print (df)

In [87]: %timeit df.eq(1).mul(df.index, axis=0)
684 ms ± 36.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [90]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.eq(1),df.index.to_numpy()[:, None],''),index = df.index, columns = df.columns)
449 ms ± 26.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[idx] = ['' if val == 0 else idx for val in row]
```

which gives:

```
   A  B  C
x  x  x   
y     y  y
z        z
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the fact that `1*'x' -> 'x'` and `0*'x' -> ''`:

```
out = df.eq(1).mul(df.index, axis=0)
```

*NB. the `eq(1)` converts the float to boolean as `True` is equivalent to `1`. You could also use `astype(int)` if you only have `0./1.`.*

Output:

```
   A  B  C
x  x  x   
y     y  y
z        z
```